# How to get Screen Size using ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I need to change the cardView height according to screen height. how can I get the Screen Height inside the TileAdapter?

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

    public CardView cardView;

    // ........................

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        Display mdisp = itemView.getContext().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point mdispSize = new Point();
        mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
        height = mdispSize.y;

        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),height,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cardView.setMinimumHeight(height);
    }

    // ..........................
}
```

Comment: what is the output of toast

Comment: try this - 

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

int width = display.getWidth();

int height = display.getHeight();

Comment: The easiest way is to pass the root view height through the adapter constructor

Comment: I got following Exception android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x320

Answer (score 0):

Try this - 
[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

Use **DisplayMetrics** instead of **Display**